# How to verify a random number generation and provide a calculation

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automation, seetest

I have a Website https://www.ultimateqa.com/complicated-page/ on the website there is a form to fill in that has a Captcha which produces random numbers and asked the user to do the addition and enter a number.

I am trying to do this on Selenium using Java.

How can I verify the random numbers, take themr, do the calculation and then add the answer to the input field?

Comment: Use pattern to verify one digit or 2 digit number? `Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1}");` or `Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}");`

Comment: Get the string 'X + Y = ', using split and/or replace you can extract X and Y, finally convert those to integers.

Comment: @pbugr How would I do this, I am obviously pretty new to this....I can find the field which is et_pb_contact_captcha_question, but how to extract the X + Y is a little bit to much for me.

Comment: This is what I tried earlier    

**public void Capta() {**
  
  **WebElement X = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"et_pb_contact_form_0\"]/div[2]/form/div/div/p/span"));**
  
  **System.out.println("Calculation print out" + X);**

What I am trying to do is to locate the numbers and pass the value to 'X'  I am then going to split them, the issue I have is that I am using the BY.Xpath, I think this locating the element but not the value in the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Locate web element holding the captcha challenge

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("et_pb_contact_captcha_question"));
   ```
2. Get its text into a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

   ```
   String captchaText = element.getText();
   ```
3. Evaluate the string value using i.e. [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)

   ```
   String captchaResult = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript").eval(captchaText).toString();
   ```
4. That should be it:

   [image]

In more complex captcha challenges where you cannot find the values in the page source you will have to go for an OCR or image recognition library like [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) or [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) or [SeeTest](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDB/SeeTestAutomation-+Text+%28OCR%29+recognition)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and get back to you